# How to call SQL Function from Spring @Query Annotation

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data

What is wrong with the syntax here:

```
@Modifying
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "delete from simple_token where simple_token.expiry < NOW()")
int deleteExpiredTokens();
```

I get the exception

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 's where s.expiry < now()' at line 1
```

But the query taken 'as is' will execute fine in a MYSQL client.

What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, I was an idiot. The sql 'as is' did not work in a mysql client. I changed the code to this:

```
@Modifying
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "delete from simple_token where expiry < NOW()")
int deleteExpiredTokens();
```

and it now works fine

Answer (score 0):

You declared query and syntax error are different. `where s.expiry < now()` in the exception but where `simple_token.expiry < NOW()` in the `@Query`. Looks like you run wrong query. may be alias is incorrect

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was a daft error by me. One reason for my confusion was that IntelliJ 14 was complaining about the `now()` function even though it is perfectly legal to use it. A case of over reliance on the IDE